# Shall we ask questions which are not really questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes some questions will suddenly bump in my mind while actually they have no practice use. Sometimes I'll even 'make' questions according to these ideas.

They're great ideas, but they cannot solve present problems. Shall I post these questions?

e.g.:[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119265/automatically-add-debug-contents-to-a-program) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119223/mysterious-behaviour-of-pick) are all partially made-up questions......

As a new-comer (though I'm already 1000+ rep but you can see that I gain them in less than one month, so I think that is 'new'), just the same like other new-comers, I'm eager to contribute to this community and also eager to gain votes(Though a bit childish, but I'll have to admit that several upvotes can lit my day up......), I believe these questions are interesting and can attract some votes. But I think these questions can be a waste of answers time as they devote their precious time to some make-up questions.

Comment: Certainly, ask such questions, if they are of general interest.

Comment: I'm just surprised your dog cares about your upvotes. 

But of course, these "how would I do this in Mathematica?" kind of questions are valid even if they have no (current) practical use to you - I often think of some weird "what if", tinker with it, and have notebooks full of solutions that end up getting used when an actual need presents itself.

Comment: @ciao, funny you should say that: I have a bunch of folders filled with unfinished artwork and partially debugged programs, and it has happened that stuff I used in those turned out to be useful for answering questions posed here that were completely unrelated to whatever I was using them for.

Comment: @ciao spelling mistakes…… It should be 'lit my day up' not 'lit my dog'

Comment: @Wjx I know, just pulling your chain with reference to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH64dlgyydM)...

Comment: @ciao Do you know we cannot visit youtube in china?

Comment: well I used a VPN to have a look at it~ DAGS :P